# Listening to multiple clients with TCP server

Tags: c#, tcp

We are just making a small quiz with TCP server. We can connect one client to the server but with multiple the server crashes. Ignore the dutch in it. 
It can be that there are some non-logic things in it cause we have  been playing with it for some hours.

Our code for the server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Simpele_Server
{
class Program
{
    const int portNr = 2000;        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        string antwoord = "";
        string client1Ant = "";
        string client2Ant = "";
        string client3ant = "";
        System.Net.IPAddress localAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.145.4.43");
        //Luister op het eigen IP-adres: 127.0.0.1 (Loop back adres)
        TcpListener mijnListener = new TcpListener(localAddress, portNr);
        mijnListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("\n Wachten op verbinding...\n");
        while (true)
        {
        //Aanvaard het binnenkomende verzoek
        TcpClient eenClient = mijnListener.AcceptTcpClient();

        //Gebruik een 'NetworkStream object' om gegevens te verzenden en te ontvangen
        NetworkStream ns = eenClient.GetStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[eenClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

        //Lees de binnenkomende 'stream' --> Read() is een 'blocking call'
        int numBytesRead = ns.Read(data, 0,System.Convert.ToInt32(eenClient.ReceiveBufferSize));
        antwoord = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);



        if (antwoord.Substring(0, 8).Equals("Client1:"))
        {
            client1Ant = antwoord;

            Console.WriteLine(obj.ControleerAntwoorden1(client1Ant));
        }
        if (antwoord.Substring(0, 8).Equals("Client2:"))
        {
            client1Ant = antwoord;
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ControleerAntwoorden2(client2Ant));
        }
        if (antwoord.Substring(0, 8).Equals("Client3:"))
        {
            client1Ant = antwoord;
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ControleerAntwoorden3(client3ant));
        }

        //Beeld de ontvangen data af
        Console.WriteLine("Ontvangen: " + antwoord);
    }
        //Voorkom onmiddellijk sluiten van het venster
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private int ControleerAntwoorden1(string antwoord)
    {
        int punten = 0;
        string antw;
        antw = antwoord.Replace("Client1:", "");
        //antw = antwoord.Replace("Client2:", "");
        //antw = antwoord.Replace("Client3:", "");
        Console.WriteLine(antw);



        string ant1 = antw.Substring(0, 1);
        string ant2 = antw.Substring(1, 1);
        string ant3 = antw.Substring(2, 1);
        string ant4 = antw.Substring(3, 1);


        if (ant1.Equals("1"))
            punten++;
        if (ant2.Equals("2"))
            punten++;

        if (ant3.Equals("3"))
            punten++;
        if (ant4.Equals("4"))
            punten++;

        return punten;
    }
    private int ControleerAntwoorden2(string antwoord)
    {
        int punten = 0;
        string antw;
        //antw = antwoord.Replace("Client1:", "");
        antw = antwoord.Replace("Client2:", "");
        //antw = antwoord.Replace("Client3:", "");
        Console.WriteLine(antw);



        string ant1 = antw.Substring(0, 1);
        string ant2 = antw.Substring(1, 1);
        string ant3 = antw.Substring(2, 1);
        string ant4 = antw.Substring(3, 1);


        if (ant1.Equals("1"))
            punten++;
        if (ant2.Equals("2"))
            punten++;

        if (ant3.Equals("3"))
            punten++;
        if (ant4.Equals("4"))
            punten++;

        return punten;
    }
    private int ControleerAntwoorden3(string antwoord)
    {
        int punten = 0;
        string antw;
        //antw = antwoord.Replace("Client1:", "");
        //antw = antwoord.Replace("Client2:", "");
        antw = antwoord.Replace("Client3:", "");
        Console.WriteLine(antw);



        string ant1 = antw.Substring(0, 1);
        string ant2 = antw.Substring(1, 1);
        string ant3 = antw.Substring(2, 1);
        string ant4 = antw.Substring(3, 1);


        if (ant1.Equals("1"))
            punten++;
        if (ant2.Equals("2"))
            punten++;

        if (ant3.Equals("3"))
            punten++;
        if (ant4.Equals("4"))
            punten++;

        return punten;
    }
}
}
```

Our client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace client
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      const int poortNr = 2000;
    //string ipadres = "127.0.0.1";
    string ipadres = "10.145.4.43";
    string strRead = null;
    int intBytesRead;
    string[] vragen = { "1. In welk jaar is 9/11 gebeurt?" + Environment.NewLine + "    A = 2001"  + Environment.NewLine + "    B = 2000 " + Environment.NewLine + "    C = 1999" + Environment.NewLine + "    D = 1998",
                      "2. Welke kleur heeft een wolk?" + Environment.NewLine + "     A = Blauw " + Environment.NewLine + "     B = Groen " + Environment.NewLine + "     C = Wit " + Environment.NewLine + "     D = geel",
                      "3. Leeft Steve Jobs nog? " + Environment.NewLine + "    A = Nee " + Environment.NewLine + "    B = Ja " + Environment.NewLine + "    C = Steve jobs heeft nooit bestaan " + Environment.NewLine + "    D = test",
                      "4. test"};
    string antwoorden = "";
    int counter;
    int aantalcounter = 2;
    int vraagnr = 0;
    TcpClient mijnClient = new TcpClient();



    private void startTimer()
    {
        counter = aantalcounter;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void resetTimer()
    {
        counter = aantalcounter;
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void stopTimer()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    public NetworkStream getNS()
    {
        //networkstream
        NetworkStream mijnNS = mijnClient.GetStream();
        return mijnNS;
    }

    public void disableRadiobuttons()
    {
        radioButton1.Enabled = false;
        radioButton2.Enabled = false;
        radioButton3.Enabled = false;
        radioButton4.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void uncheckRadiobuttons()
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
    }

    //verzend data naar server
    public void verzendData(string tekst)
    {
        byte[] aDataTeVersturen = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tekst);

        getNS().Write(aDataTeVersturen, 0, aDataTeVersturen.Length);
    }

    //zoek selected antwoord
    public string getAntwoord()
    {
        string qsdf = "Client1: ";
        string answer = "";
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            answer = "1";
        }
        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            answer = "2";
        }
        if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            answer = "3";
        }
        if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            answer = "4";
        }
        if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == false && radioButton3.Checked == false && radioButton4.Checked == false)
        {
            answer = "0"; //geen antwoord
        }
        qsdf += answer; 
        return qsdf;
    }

    //alle antwoorden opslaan in lange string
    public void opslaanAntwoorden(string antwoord)
    {
        antwoorden += antwoord;
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtVraag.Text = vragen[vraagnr];
        startTimer();
        try
        {
            mijnClient.Connect(ipadres, poortNr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnVerbreek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getNS().Close();
        mijnClient.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtAntwoord_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnOntvang_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //data van server krijgen
        byte[] aDataOntvangen = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(mijnClient.ReceiveBufferSize)];
        intBytesRead = getNS().Read(aDataOntvangen, 0, Convert.ToInt32(mijnClient.ReceiveBufferSize));
        strRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aDataOntvangen, 0, intBytesRead);
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtVraag_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCount.Text = counter.ToString();
        counter--;
        if (counter == -1)
        { 
            resetTimer();
            startTimer();

            opslaanAntwoorden(getAntwoord()); //antwoorden opslaan in 1 lange string

            if (vraagnr != vragen.Length-1)
            {
                txtVraag.Text = vragen[vraagnr + 1];
                volgendeVraag();
                uncheckRadiobuttons();
            }
            else
            {
                verzendData(antwoorden); //zend alle antwoorden (einde van quiz)
                txtVraag.Text = "Einde van quiz";
                uncheckRadiobuttons();
                disableRadiobuttons();

                //timer op 0 + stoppen
                stopTimer();
                counter = 0;
                txtCount.Text = counter.ToString();
            }

        }



    }
    private void volgendeVraag()
    {
        vraagnr++;
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lblCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? my code doesnt look that different ( I have some nasty code that basically works a mud/muck type game)

Comment: Your basic problem is the sequential `while (true){ TcpClient eenClient = mijnListener.AcceptTcpClient(); /*..*/}` loop, you must restructure it with callbacks and make use of `.BeginAcceptTcpClient()` to be able to accept multiple connections. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a *lot* of code here - please reduce it to a [mcve]. You may well find that while doing so, you find the problem. You should give details of *exactly* how it crashes, too.